# What is the difference between fixed width html block and elastic. Different behavior with same condition

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I cannot understand how it is working, I'm talking about HTML's percentage width blocks.
I'm using chrome on windows OS.
Here's my [testcase example](http://bloknotus.com/test.php)

There are 1 wrap div block with 60% width, inside it theres another block.
And inside that second block there are two more. They have fixed width of 345 and 346 px.
If you resize window in testcase size ( #gallery must have 691px width, there is info block that will help you do so).
So we have 691px block and inside it two blocks with 345 and 346 px, but they will not fit the parent block while it has not fixed div. To illustrate this, I've added "toggle" link in the blue block, by clicking it you're toggling 'fixed' class on #wrap, so it lose its 60% and gain 691, when it's done, all child blocks fit container perfectly.

I cannot understand what is going on :) Please help me.
(I'm trying to create my yet another image gallery, so I need images, blocks, doesn't matter what... entities to fit the container that has specific width.

upd. about borders, margins... there's normalize.css included, so it vaniches it with its *{box-sizing: border-box} rule

Comment: Instead of giving width in pixels to boxes, try to give in percentage. Now if you will re size you page , UI will be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is rounding, though:

1151 * 0.6 = 690.6